# Securing embedded video

Tags: flash, embed

https://www.ikeyless.com/vehicles/Ford/Expedition/2005/1000865

There's an embedded video on that key showing how it works that when viewed in IE shows the unsecure prompt.  The problem is, everything is secure.  The relative paths to the `swf` I changed to https:// directly linking to the file and it doesn't fix it... when I remove the prompt goes away?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a request to the crossdomain.xml or something to that nature? I see you're pulling your video from an Amazon service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using something like Chrome or Firefox with Firebug, which can show you all resources loaded. In your case, it looks like the flash movie popup is trying to load:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/images/jwbox/closelabel.gif

Over plain HTTP.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the Firebug net tab to determine secure status, good call